# How to add a new column with foreign key constraint in a single statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

How to add a new column with `foreign key` `constraint` in a single statement in `oracle`?Can any one give an example query?

Comment: would disabling the constraint then enabling it will do the trick ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
    alter table tab1
    add c1 number(20) constraint tab1_c1_fk references tab2(c2);
```

`c1` new column in the table `tab1`  with the FK `tab1_c1_fk` on the table `tab2` column `c2`.

Comment: At least as of 11, `constraint constraint_name` isn't strictly necessary. It could just be `add c1 number(20) references tab2(c2)`.

Answer (score 13):

```
ALTER TABLE CODE_LIST_TYPE_ERROR 
ADD ID_CODE_LISTS VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT CODE_LIST_TYPE_ERROR_FK REFERENCES CODE_LISTS(ID);
```

***oracle query to modify table and add new column which is refrence of another table***